# React Set state not working on first click (api slowdown)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a web app utilizing the Poke API to show multiple Pokemon. I'm trying to have buttons to "change the page" and change the API URL to the next or previous set of Pokemon, but for some reason, the buttons won't change the page on the very first click but will work on subsequent clicks. In console.log, the state and API URL just doesn't change on the first click. Additionally, the first time I hit the previous page after moving forward doesn't move the page backward but instead moves it forward. How do I fix this?

EDIT: After looking through some other posts it looks like the reason has to do with React doing this all asynchronously and I think that it takes too long for the API to update and update all the other data before rendering all the Pokemon. So now I'm wondering how should I force it to wait for the API and data to fully update?

```
function App() {
  const [currentApiURL, setCurrentApiURL] = useState("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27&offset=0"); //https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27&offset=0
  const [nextApiURL, setNextApiURL] = useState("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27&offset=27");
  const [prevApiURL, setPrevApiURL] = useState();
  const [multPokemonUrls, setMultPokemonUrls] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(currentApiURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setMultPokemonUrls(data.results.map(data => data.url));
        setNextApiURL(data.next);
        setPrevApiURL(data.previous);
      })
  }, [currentApiURL])

  function nextPage() {
    setCurrentApiURL(nextApiURL);
    console.log(currentApiURL);
  }

  function prevPage() {
    setCurrentApiURL(prevApiURL);
    console.log(currentApiURL);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => {prevPage()}> Prev</button>
        <button onClick={() => {nextPage()}> Next</button>
      </header>
      
      <div className="App-pokemoncontainer">
        {multPokemonUrls.map((poke) =>
          <Pokemon url={poke} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fetch all the pokemonUrls you do a fetch to all the URLs using `Promise.all`

Also your `</header>` doesn't have an opening tag and `onClick` handlers are now correct

`onClick={() => {prevPage()}` should be `onClick={() => prevPage()}`

`onClick={() => {nextPage()}` should be `onClick={() => nextPage()}`

So remove the `multPokemonUrls`  in the state and replace it with new state (Ex: `multPokemons`) where you fetch all the urls and get final data (`All pokemons data`).

I used ur code and did the above mentioned changes [**here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bas-irn0c).